# Using BasedOn Style Property on DynamicResources

Tags: wpf, xaml

i wonder if there is a way to use the basedOn property of wpf styles with dynamicresources. e.g.

```
<Style BasedOn="{DynamicResource somestyle}">
   <Setter Property="SomeProp" Value="SomeValue"/>
</Style>
```

this e.g. throws an error indicating that the usage of dynamicresources in combination with BasedOn styles is not possible.
i wonder how someone could do that?
thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the main reason is sealed objects. If you have a Style hierarchy:

```
       Style A
      /       \
  Style A1  Style A2
```

this might not be a difficult scenario. You refer to `StyleA` using a dynamic resource, so whenever that resource changes, `Style A1` and `Style A2` should change their `BasedOn` property. However, once a Style is being used in your application, it becomes a sealed object. `Style A` becomes immutable.

One workaround you can use is:

1. `Style A` needs to change.
2. Create a new Style object that is going to be the new `Style A` resource.
3. Create a new version of `Style A1` and `Style A2`. You'd need to write a copy procedure that makes copies of all the `Setters`, `Resources`, etc. Set the `BasedOn` to the new version of `Style A`.
4. Update the resources collection so that the three new styles are in there.

`{DynamicResource StyleA1}` and `{DynamicResource StyleA2}` should now pick up the fact that those resources changes (from step 4) and update any references automatically.

Note that this is a very simple scenario. Real world style hierarchies can be more complex, especially if they are spread across multiple files and come from merged dictionaries.

Hope I understood your problem and helped out.

Comment: How about this scenario - A different (Ux) team creates the base styles... a developer wants to set a couple of properties in addition to the base style. Ideally this is a scenario where DevStyle BasedOn "DynamicResource UxStyle" would have helped.. If this is not possible, what are the alternatives to merge 2 styles before applying it to a control ?

Answer (score 16):

I've found that since you can't use `BasedOn` on a `DynamicResource`, you can "convert" the `DynamicResource` to `StaticResource` by merging the `ResourceDictionary` holding your "parent" resources to your current Window/UserControl/whatever. This way you are now able to refer to the resource object (eg. `Style`) using `StaticResource`. This way you can use `Datatriggers` on `DynamicResource` (through conversion).

Example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject.Styles;component/ButtonStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        [*Your other resources can be put here*]
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

...

<Button Command="{Binding MyCommandInViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleFromButtonStyles}" TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBool}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Button.Content" Value="{StaticResource SomeImage}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBool}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Button.Content" Value="{StaticResource SomeOtherImage}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Hence `Datatriggers` are applied to a button styled in an imported `ResourceDictionary`.

Hope this helps!