# MAUI global font size

Tags: maui

in WPF can set the global font size for all control, [WPF global font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893428/wpf-global-font-size)

in MAUI, how to set the global font size in Resources/Styles/Style.xaml

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried that before but some controls with Text and FontSize properties derived from View class and InputView, but these classes not had FontSize property. My suggestion is create a Base control with all this basic properties as WPF and create your own controls. It's ugly but works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to style.xaml. There you can search for the label style and the other objects where you want to set the fontsize property.