# WPF - changing background button

Tags: wpf

i would like change background color using binding. When i dont use `Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"`, Background changes. This is my code:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" Content="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.SelectButton}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}" ToolTip="{Binding Description}">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>

                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                </Button>
```

How i change background color in button using trigger? can be a trigger to insert a reference to style?

Comment: Does the Button have to use `ButtonStyle` as a `DynamicResource`? If you can refer that style as a `StaticResource` then you may be able to create set a style for button `BasedOn` this `ButtonStyle` and your tiggers to it. You may want to refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9326453/587690)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a value converter instead a style if you cannot apply the trigger to the control template of the button or the style.

```
Background="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource SelectedToBackgroundConverter}}"
```

Or with style

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <Setter  Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Or control template

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Width="200" Height="20" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="myGrid" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="myGrid" Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```